# Azure AKS Deploy using Github Actions

Tags: kubernetes, github-actions, azure-aks

I am trying to automate my deployment to Azure AKS, but trying to work out how to reference the image name in my manifest file. At the moment I have commented out the image name in the manifest file so see if that works but getting an error:

> ##[error]TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined

**This is my  Github workflow file:**

```
on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@master
    
    - uses: Azure/docker-login@v1
      with:
        login-server: registry.azurecr.io
        username: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.REGISTRY_PASSWORD }}
    
    - run: |
        docker build . --file Dockerfile_nginx -t registry.azurecr.io/k8sdemo:${{ github.sha }}
        docker push registry.azurecr.io/k8sdemo:${{ github.sha }}
      
    - uses: Azure/k8s-set-context@v1
      with:
        kubeconfig: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG }}
      

    - uses: Azure/k8s-deploy@v1
      with:
        manifests: |
          k8s/mg-k8s/nginx.yaml
        images: |
          registry.azurecr.io/k8sdemo:${{ github.sha }}
        imagepullsecrets: |
          secret
```

**This is my manifest file:**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginxstaticservice
  namespace: mg-staging
  labels:
    app: nginxstatic
spec:
  selector:
    k8s-app: traefik-ingress-lb
  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      protocol: TCP
  # selector:
  #   app: nginxstatic

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginxstatic-deployment
  namespace: mg-staging
  labels:
    app: nginxstatic
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginxstatic
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginxstatic
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginxstatic
        # image: 
        imagePullPolicy: "Always"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80

        volumeMounts:
          - name: nginx-config
            mountPath: /etc/nginx/conf.d
      volumes:
        - name: nginx-config
          configMap:
            name: nginx-configmap
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: secret
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: @Rutnet figured out the way to pass the new tag using `Azure/k8s-deploy1@1` action. From the [docs](https://github.com/Azure/k8s-deploy):

> (Optional) Fully qualified resource URL of the image(s) to be used for
> substitutions on the manifest files. This multiline input accepts
> specifying multiple artifact substitutions in newline separated form.
> For example -
>
> ```
> images: |   
> contosodemo.azurecr.io/foo:test1  
> contosodemo.azurecr.io/bar:test2
> ```
>
> In this example, all references to
> `contosodemo.azurecr.io/foo` and `contosodemo.azurecr.io/bar` are searched
> for in the image field of the input manifest files. For the matches
> found, the tags test1 and test2 are substituted.

Based on the documentation, the manifest file needs to have references to the original image with a default tag. The action will replace the tags with the ones specified. The manifest in question has the `image` commented. It should have been something like:

```yaml
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginxstatic
        image: registry.azurecr.io/k8sdemo:some_tag
```

---

Original Reply:

There are several ways of achieving this. You can use templating tools like [Helm](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/quickstart/) or [Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize). In this case, you can just use [sed](https://askubuntu.com/a/20416) before you apply the manifest. Add a place holder in the manifest file and replace that with sed inline. See the following example:

```
...
- run: |
    sed -i.bak "/NGINX_IMAGE_URL/registry.azurecr.io\/k8sdemo:${{ github.sha }}" k8s/mg-k8s/nginx.yaml

- uses: Azure/k8s-deploy@v1
      with:
        manifests: |
          k8s/mg-k8s/nginx.yaml
        images: |
          registry.azurecr.io/k8sdemo:${{ github.sha }}
        imagepullsecrets: |
          secret
...
```

Add the NGINX_IMAGE_URL place holder in the manifest file:

```
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginxstatic
        image: NGINX_IMAGE_URL
...
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for this. I got it resolved using an alternative method where I just passed the image name to the manifest. The workflow file automatically uses the tag. So I just pass "registry.azurecr.io/k8sdemo" into the manifest file

Comment: I have added your finding in the answer as well. Please let me know if I missed anything.